# Как правильно кастомизировать центральный слайдер в owl-carousel 1?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На страницу выводятся 3 слайда. Центральный больше остальных по высоте и ширине. Проблема в том, что при переходе не следующие слайды, они съезжают в сторону.. При инициализации даю центральному ширину и высоту. BeforeMove - убирает этот размер, а AfterMove снова дает центральному элементу большие размеры. В чем может быть проблема? И как можно кастомизировать центральный слайд, что бы при скролле ничего не съезжало в сторону? Спасибо.

Comment: а пример ? вёрстка ? желательно в сети - что бы можно было видеть косяк , выложите на хостинг сайтов , вам щас минусов на суют под самое не хочу

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на функции слайдера:

```
// Slider
$(function() {
   $("#slider").owlCarousel({
      navigation: false,
      slideSpeed: 300,
      paginationSpeed: 400,
      //singleItem: true,
      items: 3,
      itemsDesktop: false,
      itemsDesktopSmall: false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile: false
   });
});
```